# JavaScript: How to pass an anonymous function as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I would like to write a function that accepts an anonymous function as a parameter. For example:

```
run('param1', function(){
    alert('execute this');
});

function run(param1, callback) {
    //now execute the callback parameter as a function
}
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 11):

`callback()` would invoke it.

If you need to supply a context, do `callback.apply(this, arguments)`. When you use `.apply` be aware of the current execution context, basically know what `this` will refer to, or your code will not work as expected if you are feeding a literal that references `this` inside it's function body.

Comment: hmm...seems to work fine, but firebug is complaining that `callback()` is not a function. Maybe a bug in firebug?

Comment: Are you sure it complains that `callback` isnt a function, or does it complain about `run`? Firebug says `run is not defined` for me ( Chrome console executes it perfectly ). The reason is because code evaluated in Firebug directly is not treated in the same manner as if the code was in a web page. If it's not complaining about `run` then check for typos.